# Apache directory not working with regular expression

Tags: regex, apache, directory

I'm trying to dynamically apply some rules to dynamic Directory but it's not working. When I don't use regular expression, it works :

```
<Directory ~ /mydirectory/foo/11/ >  
        RewriteEngine On            
        RewriteRule ^k(.*) test.html      [NC,L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

But when I try to use some regular expression, none of them are working :

```
<Directory ~ ^/mydirectory/foo/11/ >
<Directory ~ ^/mydirectory/foo/[0-9][0-9]/ >
<Directory ~ "^/mydirectory/foo/[0-9][0-9]/" >
<Directory ~ "/mydirectory/foo/[0-9][0-9]/" >
<Directory ~ ^/mydirectory/foo/(.*)/ >
<Directory ~ "/mydirectory/foo/(.*)/" >
<Directory ~ "^/mydirectory/foo/11" >
<Directory ~ ^/mydirectory/foo/11 >
<Directory ~ ^/mydirectory/foo/[0-9][0-9] >
<Directory ~ "^/mydirectory/foo/[0-9][0-9]" >
<Directory ~ "^mydirectory/foo/[0-9][0-9]" >
<Directory ~ ^mydirectory/foo/[0-9][0-9] >
<Directory ~ ^mydirectory/foo/11 >
<Directory ~ "^mydirectory/foo/11" >
```

It never applies the redirection, looks like it's not parsing the regular expression.

I'm using apache 2.4.29 on Linux Ubuntu desktop with mod_rewrite, mod_alias and mod_vhost_alias enabled.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `<Directory ~ "^mydirectory/foo/[0-9][0-9]" >` or  `<Directory ~ "^/mydirectory/foo/[0-9][0-9]" >`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still not working. I will edit the question to add theses cases

Comment: I can see you have an edit - but you didn't include my first example to try, note the lack of a `/` after the opening `"^`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the missing `/` but it's still not working. Is there any option to activate in apache to enable regular expression ?

Comment: Consider [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) where it states the following "If multiple (non-regular expression) `<Directory>` sections match the directory (or one of its parents) containing a document, then the directives are applied in the order of shortest match first" ... "Regular expressions are not considered until after all of the normal sections have been applied"

Comment: I took out all other vhosts. And I tried new expressions with no success:
`<Directory ~ (.*) >
<Directory ~ "(.*)" >`

Comment: Have you been restarting Apache between config changes?

Comment: Yes everytime I change some configuration, I run `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`